# Using AzureAD in Powershell to bulk change Office location using this script but no changes are being made

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Ran this If statement on changing the old office location to another office using this test script but the change is not being reflected in AzureAD nor am I getting any errors

Here is the script:

```
# Specify the old and new office names
$oldOfficeName = "Test"
$newOfficeName = "Live Test"

# Get all users from Azure AD
$allUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $true

# Loop through each user and update the attribute if the old office name matches
foreach ($user in $allUsers) {
    if ($user.ExtensionProperty["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"] -eq $oldOfficeName) {
        $user.ExtensionProperty["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"] = $newOfficeName
        Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -ExtensionProperty $user.ExtensionProperty
        Write-Host "Office name updated for $($user.UserPrincipalName)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether $user.ExtensionProperty["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"] returns value, and that $user.ExtensionProperty["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"] = $newOfficeName is actually setting the value? You could just write-host before and after to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sample, in my environment to fetch the users with **OfficeLocation "Test"**, I used the below command:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object {$_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq "Test"}
```

[image]

To update all the users with **OfficeLocation "Test"** to new **OfficeLocation "Test Live"**, use below script:

```
# Get all users with office location "Test"
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object {$_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq "Test"}

# Loop through each user and update the office location to "Test Live"
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName "Test Live"
    Write-Host "Updated office location for $($user.UserPrincipalName)"
}
```

[image]

**The users are updated with new OfficeLocation successfully:**

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object {$_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq "Test Live"}
```

[image]

After update there are no users with **OfficeLocation "Test"**:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object {$_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq "Test"}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that it worked effectively in my current setting. Now, for a subsequent inquiry, would it be feasible to employ this identical approach but modify the criteria for all the dynamic groups I possess, so that the condition changes from (user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq 'Test') to (user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq 'Test Live')?